# Symfony - Composer installed maker-bundle and forgot --dev

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I installed the maker-bundle like this:

`composer require symfony/maker-bundle`

I forgot to add --dev so it only installs for the dev environment. How can I fix that? Is it as easy installing it again like this?

`composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`

Or something like in composer.json move this into the "require-dev" section?

```
"symfony/flex": "^1.2",
"symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20"
```

I'm not sure how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not simply check what happens when running `--dev`? The JSON file is human-readable, so you can inspect what gets written into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should probably do, is remove the bundle, and then install it again with `--dev`.

Removing:

`composer remove symfony/maker-bundle --update-with-dependencies`

Installing:

`composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`

Comment: Forgot to mention that it worked. Thanks.